# Mina2 with Apache Camel, decoder concurrency

Tags: java, apache-camel, mina

I am using Mina2 with Camel to connect to a TCP server (over SSL).
Because Mina2 doesn't provide a default byte array decoder so I had to write a one on my own.

So, for some reasons, Mina splits the data received in chunks and calls the decode function multiple times and when I dug through the documentation, it says multiple threads could handle the received data and try to decode n number of times.
Here's the text:

> MINA ensures that there will never be more than one thread simultaneously executing the decode() function for the same IoSession, but it does not guarantee that it will always be the same thread. Suppose the first piece of data is handled by thread-1 who decides it cannot yet decode, when the next piece of data arrives, it could be handled by another thread.

Now because I have a mina endpoint for I/O, camel maintains the same I/O session object for all transfers.

I am saving the decoder state using IOSession.setAttributes, say no. of bytes received so far for **that particular exchange**, and finish decoding when I receive the whole message.

My fear is that if there are two different exchanges going simultaneously and these different threads compete for the **same IOSession property**, the properties could get corrupt. I also can't seem to access the camel exchange property in Mina's decoder function, so I can't uniquely identify that particular exchange.

Any help in this regard would be great!!

Comment: Look at Apache Mina it ought to have a set of decoders/encoders, for byte based, see in the org.apache.mina.filter.codec source code for examples

Comment: Thanks Claus! I found Mina2UdpProtocolCodecFactory which is a byte based codec. Although it doesn't account for situations where TCP IP requires multiple I/O on socket ( Decoder would be called as many times as the data is read ).Am I stuck using  CumulativeProtocolDecoder ?